# How reliable is the IP address logged in an Apache access log?

Tags: http, ip, spam, bots, spoofing

My website is suffering from an apparent bot which GETs a particular URL 5 times within a second, waits exactly 2 minutes, then repeats. The request is coming from the same IP address each time, and I have not observed any malicious payload, so I'm undecided on whether it is some form of spam bot. The User-Agent claims to be IE6, which is always suspicious in such an obviously non-human request pattern.

Anyway, I have done a reverse lookup on the IP and have located a contact at that domain, but am I wasting my time trying to get in touch with them? If it's a spam bot, won't the IP address be spoofed? How common is IP address spoofing in HTTP spammers? Does the HTTP protocol make it difficult in any way?

Comment: Best asked on ServerFault - this question is not programming related.

Comment: If you're running apache (and all else fails) insert this into your config: Deny from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you spoof the IP, you won't get any response to your http request. Other than that, the http protocol doesn't make spoofing any easier or harder.

However, the IP address will be that of the last proxy server or load balancer between the source and your server, so if it is malicious, I would expect they're going through some open proxy and you won't easily be able to trace them back.

If it's just accidental misconfiguration, you're in with more of a chance.

Does the URL they are returning exist on your site?

Can you configure your web server to return an error (401 Forbidden , 500 Internal server error, 301 permanent redirect, perhaps) only to GETs from that address? If the other end starts getting errors maybe they'll investigate and fix things)

Comment: The URL does exist, and it has always returned an HTTP error code (by design). If the IP was spoofed, then I guess my server's response would be directed at the spoofed IP - i.e. could my server be being tricked into participating in a DDOS attack on the IP in question?

Comment: Possible but unlikely, I'd say. I think it's more likely some misconfigured monitoring app...

Answer (score 0):

You should contact the persons in charge of the domain.  Usually, the IP address won't be spoofed (that's hard).  Most probably, one of there computers got infected by malicious software, and they definitely want to know that.  It's more about doing a favour to them than about your own network security.

Comment: I will definitely contact those persons.